# Finding similar number patterns in table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, let's suppose we have `members` table. There is a field called, let's say, `about_member`. There will be a string like this `1-1-2-1-2` for everybody. Let's suppose member_1 has this string `1-1-2-2-1` and he searches who has the similar string or as much similar as possible. For example if member_2 has string `1-1-2-2-1` it will be 100% match, but if member_3 has string like this `2-1-1-2-1` it will be 60% match. And it has to be ordered by match percent. What is the most optimal way to do it with MYSQL and PHP? It's really hard to explain what I mean, but maybe you got it, if not, ask me. Thanks.

**Edit: Please give me ideas without Levenshtein method. That answer will get bounty. Thanks. (bounty will be announced when I will be able to do that)**

Comment: Not really... What about you?

Comment: Is it always a bit mask (1 or 2)?

Comment: Re title: How about `Finding similar number patterns in table`?

Comment: I'm not sure relational DB are the best to solve the problem as you stated it. However, you may have a better solution if each digit is put in a different column instead of one single string for all digits.

Comment: Do we always have the same number of elements?

Comment: I can't do it, Banx. Because in the future it will be ~100 fields...

Comment: Ok, Banx. Let's suppose we can put it in a different columns, what is your suggestion then?

Comment: @hey - The number of columns is insignificant. What matters is the nature of the data itself. What is the nature of the data that led to this manner of storage?

Comment: I posted it below: "  Let's say members have questions and they can answer to question yes or no, if they answer yes, then it will put value 1, if no - value 2. I really don't know how to explain it better..."

Comment: Note this is properly called the "Hamming distance" (given we also ignore the hyphens, normalize by string length, and multiply by 100, of course).

Comment: @hey: The usual way to represent this is *not* to have a separate column for each answer, but rather to add a column that identifies which question each row contains the answer for. For example, one could have the following fields: <user_id, question_id, answer> and store results for as many questions as you'll ever need. Moreover, you'll be able to compute your Hamming distances with standard SQL (albeit with quadratic complexity) with joins, sums and grouping clauses. Of course, the proper solution is to do this outside the database, so this last is little more than academic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jawa posted this idea originally; here is my attempt.

`^` is the XOR function. It compares 2 binary numbers bit-by-bit and returns 0 if both bits are the same, and 1 otherwise.

```
    0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1  (number 1)
 ^  0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1  (number 2)
 =  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0  (result)
```

How this applies to your problem:

```
  // In binary...
  1111 ^ 0111 = 1000 // (1 bit out of 4 didn't match: 75% match)
  1111 ^ 0000 = 1111 // (4 bits out of 4 didn't match: 0% match)

  // The same examples, except now in decimal...
    15 ^    7 = 8  (1000 in binary) // (1 bit out of 4 didn't match: 75% match)
    15 ^    0 = 15 (1111 in binary) // (4 bits out of 4 didn't match: 0% match)
```

How we can count these bits in MySQL:

```
BIT_COUNT(b'0111') = 3 // Bit count of binary '0111'
BIT_COUNT(7) = 3       // Bit count of decimal 7 (= 0111 in binary)
BIT_COUNT(b'1111' ^ b'0111') = 1 // (1 bit out of 4 didn't match: 75% match)
```

So to get the *similarity*...

```
// First we focus on calculating mismatch.
(BIT_COUNT(b'1111' ^ b'0111') / YOUR_TOTAL_BITS) = 0.25 (25% mismatch)
(BIT_COUNT(b'1111' ^ b'1111') / YOUR_TOTAL_BITS) = 0 (0% mismatch; 100% match)

// Now, getting the proportion of matched bits is easy
1 - (BIT_COUNT(b'1111' ^ b'0111') / YOUR_TOTAL_BITS) = 0.75 (75% match)
1 - (BIT_COUNT(b'1111' ^ b'1111') / YOUR_TOTAL_BITS) = 1.00 (100% match)
```

If we could just make your `about_member` field store data as bits (and be represented by an integer), we could do all of this easily! Instead of `1-2-1-1-1`, use `0-1-0-0-0`, but without the dashes.

Here's how PHP can help us:

```
bindec('01000') == 8;
bindec('00001') == 1;
decbin(8) == '01000';
decbin(1) == '00001';
```

And finally, here's the implementation:

```
// Setting a member's about_member property...
$about_member = '01100101';
$about_member_int = bindec($about_member);
$query = "INSERT INTO members (name,about_member) VALUES ($name,$about_member_int)";

// Getting matches...
$total_bits = 8; // The maximum length the member_about field can be (8 in this example)
$my_member_about = '00101100';
$my_member_about_int = bindec($my_member_about_int);
$query = "
    SELECT 
        *,
        (1 - (BIT_COUNT(member_about ^ $my_member_about_int) / $total_bits)) match 
    FROM members
    ORDER BY match DESC
    LIMIT 10";
```

This last query will have selected the 10 members most similar to me!

**Now, to recap, in layman's terms,**

We use binary because it makes things easier; the binary number is like a long line of light switches. We want to save our "light switch configuration" as well as find members that have the most similar configurations.

The `^` operator, given 2 light switch configurations, does a comparison for us. The result is again a series of switches; a switch will be `ON` if the 2 original switches were in different positions, and `OFF` if they were in the same position.

`BIT_COUNT` tells us how many switches are `ON`--giving us a count of how many switches were different. `YOUR_TOTAL_BITS` is the total number of switches.

But binary numbers are still just numbers... and so a string of 1's and 0's really just represents a number like 133 or 94. But it's a lot harder to visualize our "light switch configuration" if we use decimal numbers. That's where PHP's `decbin` and `bindec` come in.

[Learn more about the binary numeral system.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

convert your number sequences to bit masks and use [BIT_COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count)(column ^ search) as similarity function,  ranged from 0 (= 100% match, strings are equal) to [bit length] (=0%, strings are completely different). To convert this similarity function to the percent value use

```
100 * (bit_length - similarity) / bit_length
```

For example, "1-1-2-2-1" becomes "00110" (assuming you have only two states), 2-1-1-2-1 is "10010", bit_count(00110 ^ 10010) = 2, bit-length = 5, and 100 * (5 - 2) / 5 = 60%.

Comment: could you please try to explain with queries and bounty is yours, please? Thank you.

Comment: I think what he is saying is this: `$sql = "SELECT BIT_COUNT(about_member ^ '{$search}') AS similarity FROM members";` Note that the data in about_member should be saved like 00101 instead of 1-1-2-1-2.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your search string and the about_member fields for each member. [Here's an implementation](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/) of the function as a MySQL stored function.

With that you can do:

```
SELECT name, LEVENSHTEIN(about_member, '1-1-2-1-2') AS diff 
FROM members 
ORDER BY diff ASC
```

The % of similarity is related to `diff`; if `diff=0` then it's 100%, if diff is the size of the string (minus the amount of dashes), it's 0%.

Comment: Wow, it is very interesting. And what about performance? Is it slow query? Does it "eat" a lot of resources of hosting?

Comment: @hey Honestly, I have no clue. You'd have to try and find out.

Comment: @hey - If you use the function result in an Order By or Where clause, it will force a table scan. On a large table, this would likely not perform well. If you tell us more about why you are using such a pattern, we might be able to help you find a set based solution that would perform better.

Comment: @hey: better take a closer look at how the Levenshtein distance works. I somehow doubt that this is what you had in mind - could be wrong though...

Comment: Let's say members have questions and they can answer to question yes or no, if they answer yes, then it will put value 1, if no - value 2. I really don't know how to explain it better...

Comment: No, VolkerK. I really needed this. And this method is correct, but it is not the best thing to do I guess, if it will force a table scan as Thomas says.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is to look at the levenstein distance (there isn't an implementation built into mysql but there are other implementations accesible e.g. [this one](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#552) in pl/sql and some extensions), however as usual, the right way to solve the problem would be to have normalised the data properly in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Having read the clarification comments on the original question, **the Levenshtein distance is not the answer you are looking for**.

You **are not** trying to compute the smallest number of edits to change one string into another.

You **are** trying to compare one set of numbers with another set of numbers. What you are looking for is the minimum (weighted) sum of the differences between the two sets of numbers.

Place each answer in a separate column (Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, .... )

Assume you are searching for similarities to 1-2-1-2.

SELECT UserName, Abs( Ans1 - 1 ) + Abs( Ans2 - 2 ) + Abs( Ans3 - 1 ) + Abs( Ans4 - 2) as Difference ORDER BY Difference ASC

Will list users by similarity to answers 1-2-1-2, assuming all questions are weighted evenly.

If you want to make certain answers more important, just multiply each of the terms by a weighting factor.

If the questions will always be yes/no and the number of answers is small enough that all the answers can be fitted into a single integer and all answers are equally weighted,  then you could encode all the answers in a single column and use BIT_COUNT as suggested. This would be a faster and more space-efficient implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the `similar_text()` PHP built-in. It seems to be exactly what you want:

```
$percent = 0;
similar_text($string1, $string2, $percent);

echo $percent;
```

It works as the question expects.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) approach, you can use it within [MySQL](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/) or [PHP](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you represent your answer patterns as bit sequences you can use the formula  (`100 * (bit_length - similarity) / bit_length`).

Following the mentioned example, when we convert "1"s to bit off and "2"s to bit on "1-1-2-2-1" becomes 6 (as base-10, 00110 in binary) and "2-1-1-2-1" becomes 18 (10010b) etc.

Also, I think you should store the answers' bits to the least significant bits, but it doesn't matter as long as you are consistent that the answers of different members align.

Here's a sample script to be run against MySQL.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;

CREATE TABLE `members` (
    `id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
    `about_member` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `members`
    (`id`, `about_member`)
VALUES
    ('member_1', '6'),
    ('member_2', '18');

SELECT 100 * ( 5 - BIT_COUNT( about_member ^ (
    SELECT about_member
    FROM members
    WHERE id = 'member_1' ) ) ) / 5
FROM members;
```

The magical 5 in the script is the number of answers (bit_length in the formula above). You should change it according to your situation, regardless of how many bits there are in the actual data type used, as BIT_COUNT doesn't know how many bytes you are using.

BIT_COUNT returns the number of bits set and is explained in [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count). `^` is the [binary XOR operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor) in MySQL.

Here the comparison of `member_1`'s answers is compared with everybody's, including their own - which results as 100% match, naturally.

Comment: How do you get `"1-1-2-2-1" becomes 6`?

Comment: And what `BIT_COUNT(N ^ N)` means?

Comment: As you replace "1"s with bit off (0) and "2"s with bit on (1), "1-1-2-2-1" -> 00110 (base-2) -> 6 (base-10).

Comment: Updated. For further clarification refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many fields, you could create an index on the integer representation of about_member.  Then you can find the 100% by an exact match on the about_member field, followed by the 80% matches by changing 1 bit, the 60% matches by changing 2 bits, and so on.