# Is Levenshtein slow in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, levenshtein-distance

Yesterday I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436287/finding-similar-number-patterns-in-table) where people suggested I use **Levenshtein** method. Is it a slow query? Maybe I can use something else?

Comment: I'd like to help, but the question is very broad.  Focusing on a specific piece would make it easier to discuss & give advice.

Comment: If you have a different question, then ask a new question. Don't completely change your existing one.

Comment: There is no rule about it, so you can't edit my post.

Comment: @hey - editing your question into a completely different question violates the intent and spirit of Stack Overflow. Please do not do this. You can ask new questions any time you like, as you are well aware. If you want to discuss this, please see meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Rolled back. As already mentioned: don't do that please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`BENCHMARK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) function to test the performance:

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(10000, LEVENSHTEIN('abc', 'abd'));
```

Maybe test it with different strings similar to your use case.

Comment: LEVENSHTEIN is not an integrated MySQL function. It is User Defined Function. You need to write it in C. Read the provided link to another related StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your dataset.

I found I could speed it up considerably by only comparing strings of similar length.

How similar in length your strings need to be will depend on your data.

There is an article on the subject here: <strike>http://kerbtier.ch/2008/12/30/levenshtein-to-slow-how-to-speed-it-up</strike>

Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160415095337/http://kerbtier.ch/2008/12/30/levenshtein-to-slow-how-to-speed-it-up

Answer (score 0):

If you want it perform well then **normalize your schema**.

The problem is that in order to determine how similar other data is, the DBMS has to load that data and compare it with the datum. So it has to read through every single row in the table (except the current one) to find 'similar' values. It cannot use indexes to find data which is close to the datum.

If, on the other hand you used a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE member (
   member_id      INT(11),
   member_data    CLOB,
   PRIMARY KEY (member_id));

CREATE TABLE about_member (
   member_id      INT(11),
   metric         VARCHAR(10),
   value          MEDIUMINT(9),
   PRIMARY KEY (member_id, metric),
   KEY by_value (metric, value, member_id));
```

Note that you about_member (1-1-2-2-1) string should be implemented as seperate rows, e.g.

```
 member_id     metric      value
 1234          lost        2
 1234          won         3
 1234          drawn       1
 1234          handicap    9
```

Then you can use the indexes affectively, for example with the following query.

```
 SELECT compare.member_id, SUM(ABS(compare.value-datum.value)) AS difference
 FROM about_member compare, about_member datum
 WHERE datum.member_id=$MEMBER_TO_COMPARE
 AND compare.member_id<>datum.member_id
 AND compare.metric=datum.metric
 AND compare.metric BETWEEN (datum.metric-1) AND (datum.metric+1) /* tweak here */
 GROUP BY compare.member_id;
```