# How to make this Mysql query work?

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group, analytic-functions

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_topics 
WHERE cat_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
ORDER BY last_message DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

I want to get the biggest and only one value of each cat_id (7 values total). How to correct this query to make it work if it's even possible?

There is forum topics and each has value `last_message` and I want to get the latest topic's message's time. Hope it's clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have analytical function support, which is what you're really after:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT ft.*,
               CASE 
                  WHEN @cat_id = ft.cat_id THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                  ELSE @rownum := 1
               END AS rank,
               @cat_id = ft.cat_id
          FROM FORUM_TOPICS ft
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @cat_id := -1) r
      ORDER BY ft.cat_id, ft.last_message DESC)
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

This will provide a computed column called "rank", where the most recent row based on the `last_message` column will have the value of "1" per `cat_id` value.  The outer query only gets the records whose rank value is one...

Comment: This query looks ugly as hell :/

Comment: @hey: Blame MySQL for not supporting analytic functions yet.  Until then, expect hacks like these.  Also, you should not use `SELECT *` - because I didn't know the columns in FORUM_TOPICS, you'll get all of them... plus the `rank` and the column for assigning the cat_id value in the output.

Comment: And Pony, please check this thread, maybe you will able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438833/what-classes-should-i-use-in-my-project-what-else-should-i-know-about-oop

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of confusing, but I think you are looking for this.

```
SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE cat_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) group by cat_id order by max(last_message) LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

add a group by clause like `GROUP BY cat_id`

So your query will become `SELECT * 
FROM forum_topics 
WHERE cat_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
GROUP BY cat_id
ORDER BY last_message DESC 
LIMIT 7`