# PHP/MySQL - find items that have similar or matching properties

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I'm trying to develop a way of taking an entity with a number of properties and searching for similar entities in the database (matching as many of the properties in the correct order as possible). The idea is that it would then return a % of how similar it is.

The order of the properties should also be taken into account, so the properties at the beginning are more important than the ones at the end.

For example:

> Item 1 - A, B, C, D, E
>
> Item 2 - A, B, C, D, E

Would be a 100% match

> Item 1 - A, B, C, D, E
>
> Item 2 - B, C, A, D, E

This wouldn't be a perfect match as the properties are in a different order

> Item 1 - A, B, C, D, E
>
> Item 2 - F, G, H, I, A

Would be a low match as only one property is the same and it is in position 5

This algorithm will run for thousands and thousands of records so it needs to be high performing and efficient. Any thoughts as to how I could do this in PHP/MySQL in a fast and efficient manner?

I was considering [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) but as far as I can tell that would also look at the distance between two completely different words in terms of spelling. Doesn't appear to be ideal for this scenario unless I'm just using it in the wrong way..

It might be that it could be done solely in MySQL, perhaps using a full text search or something.

This seems like a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436287/finding-similar-number-patterns-in-table), though not designed for this scenario. Perhaps binary comparison could be used in some way?

Comment: You forgot to tell us if A/B/C/D/E are fields in the same table, in different tables, all one big varchar/text/something. Please update with some table definitions.

Comment: It's completely in the theory stage at the moment so it's open to suggestion (it's going to be determined by efficiency). The actual properties will be strings but they could be compared using their numeric ids perhaps. They could be stored in separate tables and handled as a join, but that'd be pretty inefficient, so I'm wondering if they could also be cached as a string in the same table, and it just looks at the string as a whole when comparing. Another idea is that it could create some sort of fingerprint for each item and search based on that (if that would be faster)

Comment: What is the exact o/p you want? only perfect results?

Comment: Nope, just a list of all the results that partially or fully match, ordered by their % match

Comment: are all the property values known? do all entities have the same number of properties?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the strings could be fairly random. However, these values could be cached in another table if need be. The number of properties will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i'd do is encode the order and property value into a number. numbers have the advantage of fast comparisons.

this is a general idea and may still need some work but i hope it would help in some way.

calculate a number (some form of hash) for each property and multiply the number representative of the order of appearance the property for an item.

say item1 has 3 properties A, B and C.

hash(A) = 123, hash(B) = 345, hash(C) = 456

then multiply that by the order of appearance given that we have a know number of properties:

(hash(A) * 1,000,00) + (hash(B) * 1,000) + (hash(C) * 1) = someval

magnitude of the multiplier can be tweaked to reflect your data set. you'll have to identify the hash function. soundex maybe?

the problem is now reduced to a question of uniqueness due to hash collisions but we can be pretty sure about properties that don't match.

also, this would have the advantage of relative ease of checking if a property appears in another item in different order by using the magnitude of the multiplier to extract the hash value from the number generated.

HTH.

edit: example for checking matches

given item1(a b c) and item2(a b c). the computed hash of items would be equal. this is a best case scenario. no further computations are required.

given item1(a b c) and item2(d e a). computed hash of items are not equal. proceed to breaking down property hashes...

say a hash table for properties a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5 with 10^n for multiplier. computed hash for item1 is 123 and item2 is 451, break down the computed hash for each property and compare for all combinations of properties one for each item1 (which becomes item1(1 2 3) ) and item2 (which becomes item2(4 5 1) ). then compute the score.

another way of looking at it would be comparing the properties one by one, except this time, you're playing with numbers instead of the actual string values

Comment: Very interesting concept, I really like the idea of comparing numbers. I've just tried this out as a spreadsheet and I think the flaw is with the hashing. In this example the hash was simply the incremental ID of the property - 1,2,3 etc. The problem that creates is with the multiplier, where if the ID is a high number the calculated number becomes very high. Check out http://s4.postimage.org/5f0kogg2x/Screen_shot_2011_04_25_at_12_01_15.png and look at the difference between entity 1,2 and 3 - The final value of entity 3 is very high in comparison to entity 4 which has no similar values.

Comment: the numbers are expected to be relatively high. with a sample set of 8 tho, the multipliers can be increments of powers of 10. so the highest hash outcomes would be below 1000. was thinking along the lines of arbitrary precision (bigints) numbers and not just 32 or 64 bit ints.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see how it'll work.. in the example of entity 4 multiplying 4 x 10 is always going to be greater than 1 x 10 (entity 1), whereas entity 3 should be closer but is actually 8 x 10 (making it further away from entity 1 than entity 4). Look at the 'difference to entity 1' and 'order' in this picture, the order is completely wrong based on the properties of the entites -http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7570/screenshot20110425at131.png

Comment: no apologies needed. it would be my fault if i didn't get to explain it clearer. you'll still have to loop over calculated individual hashes for your comparisons.

Comment: What comparison would you make during the loop? Could you possibly give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw inspiration (or flat out algorithms) from various [sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) algorithms like [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm). Indeed what you're looking for very much seems to be a description of sequence alignment. I am, however, uncertain if it's even possible to do this as an SQL query.

Comment: indeed this is a sequence alignment problem